# Shortest road between areas

Tags: algorithm, dijkstra

I'm working on a game. I have to get the shortest road between areas and points. My problem is that there are some points that moves the player instantly to another area. I tried Dijkstra algorithm, but I don't have any idea how to implement it.

Red dots are start and finish. 0 means the point moves player instantly to another area. Numbers next to edges are distances. [image]

Comment: What do you expect us to do , implement it ? Try to do it by yourself and come back with specific problems.

Comment: Try A* which is better than Dijkstra in some scenarios and also has lots of implementations across the internet

Comment: I'd even recommend to identify points with 0 distance in order to reduce calculations cost (i.e. work on a quotient set). Btw, which language would you use?

Comment: @SamCle88 I want to use C#

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674468/finding-the-shortest-route-using-dijkstra-algorithm : what would you be missing more than this?

Answer (score 1):

Merge the nodes points that are connected via zero edges. You could do so by copying the graph in a preprocessing step -- or just alter the algorithm slightly, treating zero edges accordingly at runtime.